# Alert/Notification using Kibana3?

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, logstash, kibana

I am using `logstash-1.4.1`, `elasticsearch-1.1.1` and `kibana-3.1.0` for analyzing my logs. I am able to view and query my logs.

There's a need in which an alert/notification is needed when a particular log/event happens. Eg: When a Login failed log occurs again and again, an alert/notification (popup, via mail, etc) is required.

Presently I can query my log like for Failed login, but I want it whenever such a log appears a notification/popup appears than me manually querying for it.

Can this be done using the above three ?? How can this be achieved?

Comment: See also https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `email` option in logstash in which on detecting a certain pattern in log one can send an email. Look into docs for further reading: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/outputs/email

Answer (score 9):

You can use  **Watcher** for monitoring your Elasticsearch. It alerts you via mail.

For further details, refer to this link:
https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher

You can follow these steps to configure Watcher:

**Step 1** – Install Plugin for Watcher (for 1.7):

```
bin/plugin --install elasticsearch/watcher/latest
bin/plugin --install elasticsearch/license/latest
```

**Step 2** – Restart Elasticsearch:

```
ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch
```

**Step 3** – Verify that Watcher is set up:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_watcher/stats?pretty'
```

**Step 4** – Watch the log data for errors:

```
PUT /_watcher/watch/log_error_watch
{
    "trigger": {
        "schedule": {
            "interval": "10m"
        }
    },
    "input": {
        "search": {
            "request": {
                "indices": ["logs"],
                "body": {
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "message": "error"
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "compare": {
            "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
                "gt": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "send_email": {
            "email": {
                "to": "<username>@<domainname>",
                "subject": "Cluster logs",
                "body": "Cluster Error Logs ",
                "attach_data": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 5** – Configure email (add the lines below into `elasticsearch.yml`):

```
watcher.actions.email.service.account:
    work:
    profile: gmail
    email_defaults:
    from: <email> 
    smtp:
    auth: true
    starttls.enable: true
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    user: <username> 
    password: <password>
```

**Step 6** – To delete Watcher:

```
curl -XDELETE'http://localhost:9200/_watcher/watch/log_error_watch'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor elasticsearch using 'Watcher' (one of their products).

Here is the link with the product information: 
https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher

And in the following page you can check the product guide:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to perform email alerting and monitoring with updated ES and Kibana. I am using `elasticsearch-5.5.0`, `kibana-5.5.0` using XPack and Watcher.

Step 1. Install XPack for Elasticsearch and Kibana

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
bin/kibana-plugin install x-pack
```

Step 2. Restart ES and Kibana

```
./bin/elasticsearch
./bin/kibana
```

Step 3. Configure an email account in `elasticsearch.yml`

```
xpack.notification.email.account:
    outlook_account: 
        profile: outlook
        email_defaults: 
            from: <sender-email>
        smtp: 
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
            port: 587
            user: <username> 
            password: <password>
```

** I tried this out with sparkpost, and it worked totally fine. Just changed the profile to sparkpostmail and the host to smtp.sparkpostmail.com. You can follow the guide for other email setups: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.6/actions-email.html#configuring-email-actions

Step 4: Configure Email Actions in Kibana Dev Tools (You could do this as a curl command too)

```
PUT _xpack/watcher/watch/error_report
  {
    "trigger": {
       "schedule": {
          "interval": "1h" <OR TIME INTERVAL TO MONITOR AND ALERT>
                   }
                },
      "input": {
         "search": {
          "request": {
          "indices": [
            "logs"
                      ],
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "match": {
           "message": "error"
                   } 
              }
                }
                 }
                 }
              },
       "actions": {
         "send_email": {
         "email": {
         "to": "<YOUR EMAIL>",
         "subject": "Cluster logs",
         "body": "Cluster Error Logs ",
         "attach_data": true
                   }
                 }
               }
              }
```

OR! If you want to configure Kibana to send a dashboard or visualization via email, configure the following email action:

```
PUT _xpack/watcher/watch/error_report
{
    "trigger" : {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "<TIME_INTERVAL>"
    }
  },
  "actions" : {
    "send_email" : { 
      "email": {
        "to": "<YOUR EMAIL>",
        "subject": "Error Monitoring Dashboard",
        "attachments" : {
            "error_dashboard.pdf" : {
                "reporting" : {
                  "url": "http://<YOUR_HOST>:5601/api/reporting/generate/dashboard/<DASHBOARD_ID>?_g=(time:(from:now-7d%2Fd,mode:quick,to:now))", // This is where you configure settings like time interval
                  "retries":6, 
                  "interval":"15s", 
                  "auth":{ 
                    "basic":{
                       "username":"<USERNAME>",
                       "password":"<PASSWORD>"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 5 (optional). Delete the watcher when you are finished using Kibana's Dev Tools.

```
DELETE _xpack/watcher/watch/log_error_watch
```

This is just a concise update on the above answer for the kibana and xpack updates so it's all in one place! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a [looooong thread discussing this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1011) as an addition to Kibana (although they are naturally focusing Kibana 4 by now).

Current Status: Nope, not there yet and not even planned so far. But there are some options that get mentioned:

https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert

and

https://bosun.org/expressions.html#logstash-query-functions